# Aggregate and transform array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, functional-programming, map-function

Using javascript functional programming methods (like map/reduce), how would one aggregate/count the `status` field of `arr1` and transform it to an array of key/value objects in `arr2`.

```
arr1 = [
  {'task':'do something 1', 'status':'done'} , 
  {'task':'do something 2', 'status':'done'} , 
  {'task':'do something 3', 'status':'pending'} , 
  {'task':'do something 4', 'status':'done'}
];

// Aggregate arr1 `status` field and transform to:

arr2 = [
  {key:'done', value: 3},
  {key:'pending', value: 1}
];
```

Here's my WIP **partial** solution that handles **only** the aggregation portion. I still need the transform portion.

```
var arr2 = arr1.map(function(item) {
    return item.status;
  }).reduce(function(acc,curr,idx){
    if(acc[curr] === undefined) acc[curr] = 1;
    else acc[curr] += 1;
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Comment: I'd just do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ocqnnmw3/1/), but not sure it's "functional" enough.

Comment: Your solution doesn't give the expected answer. Or the provided answer is incorrect.

Comment: I believe @Kiril is right, the posted code produces `[done: 3, pending: 1]`, or in other words it treats an array as an object, and doesn't return the expected result ?

Comment: @adeneo, your solution is great. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @jboothe - wasn't really sure that's what you wanted, but I'll post if for posterity

Comment: there are functional libraries out there that will make this a very simple task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most functional way I could come up with. This includes both the aggregation and your desired transform:

```
var arr2 = Object.keys(arr2 = arr1.map(function(item) {
    return item.status;
}).reduce(function(acc,curr){
    acc[curr] = acc[curr] + 1 || 1;
    return acc;
}, [])).map(function(item){
    return {key: item, value: arr2[item]}
});
```

Comment: Alex, very nicely done. The only cleanup I'd make is to my own code - consolidate lines 4 & 5 into a ternary `acc[curr] === undefined ? acc[curr] = 1 : acc[curr] + 1;`

Comment: @jboothe good point! I was also thinking ternary but came up with a slightly more compact solution, what do you think?

Comment: Nifty. undefined + 1 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Array.prototype.forEach()`. Also instead of using an array, you can use object. This will save you looping over to find count of a specific status.

```js
arr1 = [
  {'task':'do something 1', 'status':'done'} , 
  {'task':'do something 2', 'status':'done'} , 
  {'task':'do something 3', 'status':'pending'} , 
  {'task':'do something 4', 'status':'done'}
];

var result = {};
arr1.forEach(function(item){
  if(!result[item.status])
    result[item.status] = 0;
  
  result[item.status]++;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing the output value as an array you should check weather the key status is present or not. If present increment its value.

```
arr2 = [];
arr1.forEach(function(item){
  var keyPresent = false;
  for(var i = 0, len = arr2.length; i < len; i++) {
      if( arr2[ i ].key === item.status ){
         keyPresent = true;
         arr2[ i ].value++
      }
  }
  if(!keyPresent){
    arr2.push({key: item.status , value : 1})
}
```

The output given by

```
arr2 = [
  {key:'done', value: 3},
  {key:'pending', value: 1}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr_done = arr1.filter(item => item.status == 'done');
const arr_pending = arr1.filter(item => item.status === 'pending');
arr2 = [
   {key:'done', value: arr_done.length}, 
   {key:'pending', value: arr_pending.length}
];
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)